# Problem deploying ceph. install ca-certificate error

Tags: 16.04, ceph

As the title says I'm having problems deploying Ceph to any of my clients. The Error message is as follows....
[Ceph error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDG2g.jpg)

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure ceph-common . take a look at the first line. this package doesn't seem to be installed correctly, or at least not fully configured.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong repos installed for your OS version.

Check the docs here: https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/install/get-packages/